# ArcPy (Python (v.2.7.8) de ArcGIS) Script con tildes o ñ no funcionan

Tags: python, ascii, arcgis

Tengo un script en arcpy (Python de ArcGIS) en 2.7.8 que se ejecuta en carpetas donde los nombres contienen caracteres como tildes o ñ. Al ejecutar me sale el siguiente error: Carácter no ASCII '\ xc2'. Tengo entendido que Python 2 solo usa ASCII en el código fuente. ¿Hay una solución para esto?.

En algunos comentarios vi que la solución era que tenía que definir la codificación de caracteres utf-8 en la primera línea de su script .py a través de la siguiente línea:

```
# - * - coding: utf-8 - * -
import arcpy
```

¿Esto funciona?

Comment: Lo has probado?

Comment: Sí y no me funciona la siguiente línea:
# - * - coding: utf-8 - * -

Después de la prueba fallida, eliminé la tilde la carpeta contenedora de los archivos que estoy ocupando y funciona.